# Python: isolating re.search results

Tags: python, regex, csv

So I have this code (probably super inefficient, but that's another story) that is pulling urls from html code of a blog.  I have the html in a .csv, which I am putting into python, then running the regex to get the urls.  Here is the code:

```
import csv, re # required imports

infile = open('Book1.csv', 'rt')  # open the csv file
reader = csv.reader(infile)  # read the csv file


strings = [] # initialize a list to read the rows into

for row in reader: # loop over all the rows in the csv file 
    strings += row  # put them into the list

link_list = []  # initialize list that all the links will be put in
for i in strings:  #  loop over the list to access each string for regex (can't regex on lists)

    links = re.search(r'((https?|ftp)://|www\.)[^\s/$.?#].[^\s]*', i) # regex to find the links
    if links != None: # if it finds a link..
        link_list.append(links) # put it into the list!

for link in link_list: # iterate the links over a loop so we can have them in a nice column format
    print(link)
```

It works, however, when I print the results it comes in the form of:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(49, 80), match='http://buy.tableausoftware.com"'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(29, 115), match='https://c.velaro.com/visitor/requestchat.aspx?sit>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(34, 117), match='https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2015/6/become->
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(32, 115), match='https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2015/6/become->
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(76, 166), match='https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2015/6/become->
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(9, 34), match='http://twitter.com/share"'>
```

Is there a way for me to just pull out the links from that other nonsense that is included?  Also, is that just a part of regex search?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `re.search` returns a [`match object`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) not the match string and you need to use [`group`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) attribute to access your desire result.

If you wants all the captured groups you can use `groups` attribute and for a special group you can pass the number of expected group to it.

In this case seems that you want the whole of match so you can use `group(0)`:

```
for i in strings:  #  loop over the list to access each string for regex (can't regex on lists)

    links = re.search(r'((https?|ftp)://|www\.)[^\s/$.?#].[^\s]*', i) # regex to find the links
    if links != None: # if it finds a link..
        link_list.append(links.group(0))
```

> **group([group1, ...])**
>
> Returns one or more subgroups of the match. If there is a single argument, the result is a single string; if there are multiple arguments, the result is a tuple with one item per argument. Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero (the whole match is returned). If a groupN argument is zero, the corresponding return value is the entire matching string; if it is in the inclusive range [1..99], it is the string matching the corresponding parenthesized group. If a group number is negative or larger than the number of groups defined in the pattern, an IndexError exception is raised. If a group is contained in a part of the pattern that did not match, the corresponding result is None. If a group is contained in a part of the pattern that matched multiple times, the last match is returned.